# C# HttpListener resets connection

Tags: c#, android

I am building a system with on one side an Android app, that uses an `HTTPURLConnection` to communicate with the other side, which is a C# `HttpListener`. Over this channel they communicate with XML data.

This works very well, except for some larger data. When I try to communicate that, I see the XML from Android arrives the C# application en the C# application does respond. However, before the data arrives the Android, I get a "Connection reset by peer." exception.

This is the Android code:

```
URL url = new URL(urlString);
connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8");
connection.setDoOutput(true);
connection.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(tel.length());
connection.setReadTimeout(30000);

// write our telegram...
OutputStream output = new BufferedOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
output.write(tel.getBytes());
output.flush();
```

and here is the reply read:

```
InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
if (connection.getResponseCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
    String r = null;
    byte cbuf[] = new byte[connection.getContentLength()];
    if (input.read(cbuf, 0, connection.getContentLength()) != -1) {
        r = new String(cbuf);
    }
    reply = Telegram.fromString(r);
} else {
   throw new ProtocolException("HTTP Error code: "+connection.getResponseCode());
}
```

and this is the C# code:

```
httpListener = new HttpListener();
httpListener.Prefixes.Add(String.Format("http://*:{0}/", port);
httpListener.Start();
```

Comment: I think this is time out. In somewhere inside the object you set time-out. Check you connection object.

Comment: @MetehanToksoy it is not a timeout. It is a Connection reset. But I'll give raising the timeout a shot.

Comment: What if viceverse? I mean your server side will has timeout?

Comment: @MetehanToksoy my server is in fact writing out (I can see using the debugger).

Comment: Did you see a part of data come in android app, debug mode? Did you try get a little data from server, is connection resets even smaller data?

Comment: @MetehanToksoy no, but that is because the receiving buffer was too large. I chunked it up and it works now (see also my own answer).

Answer (score 1):

Turns out, the `connection.getContentLength()` does not always match the number of bytes read in the `input.read()`, so the read call waits (and eventually, the server resets as it is done sending I guess).

To fix, I rewrote the receiving side to:

```
int bufs = 256, read;
ByteArrayOutputStream cbuf = new ByteArrayOutputStream(bufs);
byte[] tempbuf = new byte[bufs];

while ((read = input.read(tempbuf, 0, bufs)) != -1) {
    Log.d(PocketApplication.TAG, "Read "+read+" bytes.");
    cbuf.write(tempbuf);
}
```

and it works fine now. Making the size of `bufs` too large causes it to fail again (e.g. with 1024, the same problem occurs).